# Using query builder to write custom queries like insert, will the usual callbacks still get triggered in CakePHP 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I was reading through http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

when I found myself wondering if the usual callbacks like `Model`.`afterSave` will still triggered if I write a query like this:

```
$query = $articles->query();
$query->update()
->set(['published' => true])
->where(['id' => $id])
->execute();
```

What should I do if it does not and I still want to trigger the callbacks while using the query builder to run update operations?

The reason is because I want to update another model called `Authors` after this query is updated.

Comment: It's easy to answer the first question: _no_, except for `beforeFind`, which is triggered by query and association objects, these events are exclusive to validate/save/delete operations on table objects. In order for anyone to be able to answer your second question, it would probably help if you'd exaplain what you need these events for when executing queries directly.

Comment: Okay i have elaborated 2nd question.

Comment: That's not really what I ment, it was alrady pretty clear that you somehow want to use them, the question is why/what for/in what context exactly? I could tell you that you need to trigger them manually, but that's a very unspecific anaswer to a very unspecific question, and therefore not really suitable for SO.

Comment: I added the context where I want to update another model right after using query builder to update `Articles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to trigger callbacks using a query is by finding each record to update and saving it manually:

```
$query = $articles->query()->where(...);
foreach ($query as $entity) { $entity->published = true; $articles->save($entity); }
```

Comment: Just to clarify. The first query in your code is a select query yes?

Comment: understood. In other words, ideally to trigger aftersave callbacks would be to use CakePHP 3.x native save functions.